# Using 'case when' and null time stamp in select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, case-when

I'm using a `case when` block in postgresql to determine how results will be displayed.  The block is as follows:

```
(case 
    when four.status = 'active' and (four.expiration > (current_date + integer '{{expire_window}}')) then 'Active'
    when four.status = 'active' and (four.expiration is null) then 'Active'
    when four.status = 'pending' then 'Pending'
    when four.status = 'active' and (four.expiration <= (current_date + integer '{{expire_window}}')) then 'Expiring'

        else 'Missing' end) as certificate
```

The value `expiration` is a time stamp with time zone datatype that is null when there's nothing in it.  When expiration is null, I want four.status to show as active.  I've added that line `when four.status = 'active' and (four.expiration is null) then 'Active'`, but for some reason the results still show up as Missing.  If I only use `when four.expiration is null then 'Active'`, any results with a null expiration DO show as Active.

How can I check both `four.status = 'Active'` and `four.expiration is null` in the same `when` line to get the proper results?

Comment: It looks correct, so I'd say check your assumptions. Do the actual rows that you're expecting to catch with this condition *actually* match the conditions you're specifying?

Comment: I don't know where you misspelled, but you use both `four.status = 'active'` and `four.status = 'Active'` in your question, so heads up: the equality operator `=` is case sensitive. If you use both `'active'` & `'Active'` in your table, you might want to test the value like `lower(four.status) = 'active'`, or use citext ( http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html ), or just fix your data (f.ex. with a trigger).

Answer (score 0):

Check Whether this works for you...

```
(case 
when (four.status = 'active' 
        and ((four.expiration is null)                   
             or (four.expiration > (current_date + integer '{{expire_window}}'))
            )) then 'Active'
when four.status = 'pending' then 'Pending'
when four.status = 'active' and (four.expiration <= (current_date + integer '{{expire_window}}')) then 'Expiring'

    else 'Missing' end) as certificate
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce it

```
with four(status, expiration) as ( values
    ('active'::text, '2014-12-31'::timestamp),
    ('active', null),
    ('pending', null),
    ('active', '2014-08-15')
)
select
case
    when status = 'active' and (expiration > (current_date + 30)) then 'Active'
    when status = 'active' and (expiration is null) then 'Active'
    when status = 'pending' then 'Pending'
    when status = 'active' and (expiration <= (current_date + 30)) then 'Expiring'
    else 'Missing'
end as certificate
from four
;
 certificate 
-------------
 Active
 Active
 Pending
 Expiring
```

This is a bit cleaner

```
case status
    when 'active' then
        case
            when
                expiration is null or
                expiration > current_date + 30
                then 'Active'
            else 'Expiring'
        end
    when 'pending' then 'Pending'
    else 'Missing'
end as certificate
```